# How to create empty json object correctly using web.json in cpp?

Tags: c++, json

I want to create following json request:

```
{
  "Value1":{},
  "Value2":"some string value"
}
```

to achieve this I have tried following code in cpp:

```
json::value &refRequest
json::value jRequest = json::value();
refRequest[requestKey::Value1] = json::value(json::value::object()); //for creating empty object
refRequest[requestKey::Value2] = json::value::string("some string");
```

but it gives output as:

```
{
  "Value1":},
  "Value2":"some string value"
}
```

if you observe, instead of returning empty object as **{}** it gives the output as **}** and this results in to malformed request. I am not sure where exactly I am going wrong, any help will would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the json library?

Comment: I am using C++ rest SDK and namespace web, I am not using JsonCpp.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mistake is that you are constructing a `json::value` from a `json::value::object()`

According to the documentation the line should be fixed to:

```
refRequest[requestKey::Value1] = json::value::object();
```

Comment: Doesn't `refRequest` need to be a type `object` aswell?

Comment: No, its not necessary for my case.

Comment: Linked documentation is flagged as insecure. If possible this answer needs an updated link or just pasting the documentation in the answer so that it is self contained.